# Unable to Display IFrame Output

Tags: html, iframe

**When I use certain Links(URL), the iframes not displaying in the Output. Solution**

Code: `<iframe src="www.example.com"></iframe>`

Comment: <body>


<div id="container">
src="www.example.com>
</div>
</body>

Comment: What i am Missing ???

Comment: _“What i am Missing ???”_ - apart from how URLs work, presumably also the existence of the browser console and the `X-Frame-Options` header ...

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does not contain a protocol.

Prepend it with http:// or https:// - whatever is need for the URL

Comment: Then use: `<iframe src="http://topeducation.net/cgi-bin/Stream/6"></iframe>`

But your URL is giving 404 error - so maybe problem is there?